# Azure AD: EnforceCloudPasswordPolicyForPasswordSyncedUsers does not work for existing tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, passwords

We are currently testing the feature EnforceCloudPasswordPolicyForPasswordSyncedUsers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-password-hash-synchronization#public-preview-of-the-enforcecloudpasswordpolicyforpasswordsyncedusers-feature) which makes it possible for a tenant to comply to the Azure AD password expiration policy when a user password has expired.

By default, If the customer uses Password Hash Synchronization (PHS), the value DisablePasswordExpiration is set for every user. Which means that If a password is expired on-premise, the user is still able to make use of any Azure AD integrated services. Since we want them to comply the password expiration policy set in AD/AAD, we want this feature configured.

I have this feature working in a LAB environment with a demo M365 tenant.
**Situation LAB: 1 AAD Connect Server - 1 M365 tenant - PHS enabled - Specific OU synced - ForcePasswordChangeOnLogOn feature enabled**
When I create a new user with the feature enabled, it sets the value to DisablePasswordExpiration, when I initiate a password change on-premise it changes the value from DisablePasswordExpiration to None as expected.

Now the challenge, in the dev environment of the customer.
**Situation: 1 AAD Connect Server - 1 M365 tenant - PHS enabled - Specific OU synced - ForcePasswordChangeOnLogOn feature enabled**
When I create a new user, it does not have any value set. It should have the DisablePasswordExpiration set, but it doesn't. When I initiate a sync between on-prem and AAD, the value doesn't appear.
When I change the password on-prem for an existing user WITH the value DisablePasswordExpiration value set, it changes the value to "None". So in the above scenario for the feature does not work for newly created users, but does works for existing users.

The feature EnforceCloudPasswordPolicyForPasswordSyncedUsers is enabled in both cases.

Comment: This does not seem to be the right place for this question. This site is for developers having trouble with code. Perhaps try https://serverfault.com/

Comment: We can close this case. I am currently in discussion with Microsoft support team about the blank value.